# Compound key relationship with fuelphp orm

Tags: php, mysql, orm, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I am trying to get FuelPHP's orm to use a compound key when using the `related()` method.

I have a db setup with two tables and I'd like to relate them based on their compound keys.

For example I would normally use a relation like this in my orm model:

```
protected static $_has_one = [
    'message_flag' => [
        'key_from' => 'object_id',
        'model_to' => '\ModelClass',
        'key_to' => 'object_id',
        'cascade_save' => false,
        'cascade_delete' => false,
    ],
];
```

But instead of using `key_from => 'id` and `key_to => 'object_id`, I'd like to join them on their composite key, which might look something like this:

```
protected static $_has_one = [
    'message_flag' => [
        'key_from' => ['object_id', 'other_key'],
        'model_to' => '\ModelClass',
        'key_to' => ['object_id', 'other_key',
        'cascade_save' => false,
        'cascade_delete' => false,
    ],
];
```

To clarify, the top example, which is the one recommended in FuelPHP's docs, creates a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT `t0`.`object_id` AS `t0_c0`, `t0`.`other_key` AS `t0_c1` FROM `myTable` AS `t0` LEFT JOIN `otherTable` AS `t1` ON (`t0`.`object_id` = `t1`.`object_id`);
```

But the query that I'd like to build with the ORM would look like this:

```
SELECT `t0`.`object_id` AS `t0_c0`, `t0`.`other_key` AS `t0_c1` FROM `myTable` AS `t0` LEFT JOIN `otherTable` AS `t1` ON (`t0`.`object_id` = `t1`.`object_id` AND `t0`.`other_key` = `t1`.`other_key`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just tried my hopeful, but undocumented example above

```
protected static $_has_one = [
    'message_flag' => [
        'key_from' => ['object_id', 'other_key'],
        'model_to' => '\ModelClass',
        'key_to' => ['object_id', 'other_key',
        'cascade_save' => false,
        'cascade_delete' => false,
    ],
];
```

Surprised to say this actually worked. Still, if anyone else has a similar problem, I hope they find this answer.

Comment: Are you not missing a closing square bracket on line 5?

Comment: If this is an documented feature. You might want to consider creating a pull request to document it here: https://github.com/fuel/docs